# Generating decimal drop down list

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a drop down list range for decimals:
0
.5
1
1.5
..
..
50 <-- end value uncertain at moment

have this code

```
<div class="div-EditorFor" style="display: table-cell">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RolledOver, Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = (x / 2).ToString() }))
</div>
```

model

```
public decimal RolledOver { get; set; }
```

but can't get it to work, it generates whole values.  Have tried converting to decimal in places  but always get syntax errors.

Is there a way to do this in this format?

Thanks,

Comment: Your using integer division. Try `Value = (x / 2F).ToString()`

Comment: I assume you probably will also want `Value = (x / 2F).ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using integer division, so you need to change it to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RolledOver, Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = (x / 2F).ToString(), Value = (x / 2F).ToString() }))
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RolledOver, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => x / 2F)))
```

Comment: Great thanks! both work.  Is there any advantage of using one of the other?

I'll pass the value to an Ajax query RolledOver: $("#txtRolledOver").val() and then into the model.

Comment: Not much (and they produce identical results). The second is shorter and I find easier to read, but internally it uses reflection so a millisecond slower. Comes down to personal preference. I would however recommend that you keep your views clean and put this code in the controller and assign the `SelectList` to a view model or `ViewBag` property.

Comment: No sure what you mean by _pass the value to a ajax query and then into the model_? It already bound to the model (to property `decimal RolledOver`)

Comment: Ok thanks.  I did have a way of doing it in a class and using as a function but because I am doing this for a few different things where the value ranges are different it seemed less code and easier to read this way.

Comment: Good answer, and advice in your comments, Stephen.  There are a lot of very poor answers dealing with `SelectList` vs `SelectListItem` on SO, so it's nice to see some accuracy on the subject for a change.

Comment: @JQuery In relation to my comment above, if you'd like to know more about `SelectList` vs `SelectListItem`, I'd suggest reading [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx) and [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/03/pretty-code-1-building-selectlistitems.aspx).  Neither will take much time to read, but it's helpful to see them both together.  The comments posted underneath the second article are also worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

because Enumerable.Range(0, 50) is an enumerable of type int, doing Select on it by default assumes that we are working with an integer, when integers are divided they return integers. Specifying that you want decimal or double when using 'x' in your lambda will solve this

```
<div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RolledOver, Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((decimal)(x / 2)).ToString() })) </div>
```

Comment: Thnks, have pasted that in, rebuilt and run but it is still returning whole values from 0-49